# About the new PMI-ACP certification in comparison to PMP

Tags: agile, pmp, certification

I have started preparing for the PMP certification by the PMI institute.  I stumbled upon the PMI-ACP exam.  It's agile oriented.

My question is, what is the value of PMI-ACP in the job market?

Comment: Market-value questions are off-topic because they are generally: 1) searchable, 2) highly volatile and/or time sensitive, or 3) biased or opinion-based.

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/how-does-project-management-certification-or-lack-of-it-affect-wages.

Comment: Aside from the other close reasons and possible duplicates, my prior answer on this topic is probably the same answer I'd give here in response to this specific question: http://pm.stackexchange.com/a/6162/4271

Answer (score 2):

Surveying here will not get you either reliable or valid results. It will only reveal unsubstantiated biases. Your likely best indicator for this relatively new credential is job advertisements in your area and industry. Scan for those and see if anyone is asking for this credential. In my industry and area- it is pretty much unknown.

Even with that scan, you need to draw a limited conclusion as only like one in 10 jobs are advertised. So your sample can easily skew your findings.